# How to get Next Record from Firebase Populated on a Single TextView

Tags: android

My Database is arranged like this 
[image]
I want to be able to show the value of the next row updated in my TextView when i click on a Button. 
Here is a Sample of my code

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Transformation Quote");
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mFirebase = new Firebase("https://transformation-hour.firebaseio.com/Quotes");
        quoteText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quote_text);
        quoteId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_number);
        mFirebase.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                quoteText.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what did you expect the output to be? what was the actual output?

Comment: I want when i click on a Button it updates the TextView with the next data "2"

Comment: I want when i click on a Button it updates the TextView with the next data "2" @MohammadAthar

Comment: Please i would appreciate if someone answers me this question cause i am really stuck with the project at this stage